# Rails - eager load the number of associated records, but not the record themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, eager-loading

I have a page that's taking ages to render out.  Half of the time (3 seconds) is spent on a .find call which has a bunch of eager-loaded associations.  All i actually need is the number of associated records in each case, to display in a table: i don't need the actual records themselves.  Is there a way to just eager load the count?  Here's a simplified example:

```
@subjects = Subject.find(:all, :include => [:questions])
```

In my table, for each row (ie each subject) i just show the values of the subject fields and the number of associated questions for each subject.  Can i optimise the above find call to suit these requirements?

I thought about using a group field but my full call has a few different associations included, with some second-order associations, so i don't think group by will work.

```
@subjects = Subject.find(:all, :include => [{:questions => :tags}, {:quizzes => :tags}], :order => "subjects.name")
```

:tags in this case is a second-order association, via taggings.  Here's my associations in case it's not clear what's going on.

```
Subject
  has_many :questions
  has_many :quizzes

Question
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

Quiz
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

Grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best is using `:counter_cache` on `belongs_to` association.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject, :counter_cache => true
end
```

To use `counter_cache` you'll also need to add a `questions_count` column to your `subjects` table.

From [`railsapi.com`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M000984):

> **:counter_cache**
>  
>   Caches the number of belonging objects
>   on the associate class through the use
>   of increment_counter and
>   decrement_counter. The counter cache
>   is incremented when an object of this
>   class is created and decremented when
>   it’s destroyed [...]

Comment: Do this. It is a much better solution than the other two provided.

Comment: Thanks - a counter cache is fine in this situation as it happens and i've gone with that.  I'd still be interested in getting an answer to my original question though.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a counter cache for this purpose. I maintain a counter on an Albums model that keeps track of how many Photographs are associated with it. My process looks somewhat like this (I believe I found this method on a blog somewhere, so I take no credit for the original code):

On the Photographs model:

```
after_save :update_counter_caches
after_destroy :update_counter_caches

def update_counter_caches
  self.albums.each { |a| a.update_count } unless self.albums.empty?
end
```

On the Albums model:

```
def update_count
  update_attribute(:photographs_count, self.photographs.length)
end
```

The migration you'd need on the Albums:

```
class AddCounterCacheColumnToModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :albums, :photographs_count, :integer, :default => 0
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :albums, :photographs_count
  end
end
```

Unless I've misunderstood your question, that should be a pretty neat way of achieving what you want. It works well in my current project. :)

---

EDIT: As a note, the reason I use this setup rather than the default :counter_cache method is because I need to maintain multiple counters for multiple associations on one model. As far as I know, you can't achieve that with :counter_cache.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way I think:

```
@subjects = Subject.count(:joins => :questions, :select => 'DISTINCT(questions.id)')
```

And I am not sure for more complex query (not tested):

```
@subjects = Subject.count(:joins => [{:questions => :tags}, {:quizzes => :tags}], :select => 'DISTINCT(tags.id)'
```

Comment: Thanks floor - this isn't quite what i asked for though.  I want all the fields for subject and the number of associated questions FOR EACH SUBJECT.  This just lists the total number of associated questions for all subjects lumped together (which s the same as count(*) from questions since all questions have a subject).

Comment: Not at all, it will return count of questions which has got subject (what is really the same in this situation, but you can use it with counting tags)